# Logout on particular request mappings in spring

Tags: java, spring, logout, request-mapping

I need on a particular RequestMapping make user logout. It can be several requestMappings. It would be fine if special annotation exist to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327682/how-to-create-a-default-method-in-springmvc-using-annotations

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring authentication service (Spring Security), you can do it through configuration whereby you set a logout url and spring takes care of it.

Otherwise, you can yourself map an url as logout and upon invocation, you should invalidate the user session.

If you want to check if the user is logged in or not, you should check existence of already created session first.

Comment: Yes I use spring security. I configured logout-url. But it dont allow to use several logout urls. I need to logout user on specific addresses, for instance, when logged user enter registration url it should be logged out. And these urls can be a lot

Comment: Although I believe this is wrong use case but you can use HTTP 301 redirect to the logout url.